# In Intellij IDEA, is there a way to copy the path of the current editor tab to the clipboard?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-13, intellij-12

I'm doing some writing and would like to copy the path of the current editor tab (as shown in the tooltip here) to the clipboard:

[image: Intellij screenshot showing editor tab path]

Anyone happen to know a shortcut for this?

Comment: right click and pull down to "Copy Path" - or there's a shortcut key, but it may vary by machine.  On Mac, it's shift-command-C.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> to select current file on [**Navigation Bar**](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/navigation-bar.html):

[image]

Then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy path to a file and <kbd>Esc</kbd> come back to editor.

Comment: see sam's answer, going to the navigation bar first isn't necessary.

Answer (score 23):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> works on Windows, even if your focus is on the editor.

I assume <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will also work on a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I found Ctl+Shift+Alt+C can copy path with UNIX slash, not backslash.